Is there a way to download a folder from a remote repository where both repos are in gitlab
Am looking to have a example/plugin which supports a remote repo module folder(and all its internal files) download while compilation process of a PROJ-A maven module.
Example :
PROJ-A -- Maven project having its own submodules
PROJ-B -- npm project (needed few folders from this repo)
On compilation of maven PROJ-A one of the module needed few sass/css/js files from a remote repo of PROJ-B
I did try below plugin usage at PROJ-A module, which allows only file to file download. where as am looking to have a folder (all its inner files) download.
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-curlfile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>curl</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>--header</argument>
                                <argument>PRIVATE-TOKEN: glpat-xyza_chdf123568</argument>
                                <argument>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1202012456/repository/files/src%2Ftestfolder%2Fcomps%2Ftestfile.scss/raw?ref=development</argument>
                                <argument>--output</argument>
                                <argument>.\src\main\mydownload\components\testfolder\_downloadedfile.scss</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

